# jQuery DateTimePicker: Post datetime data to ViewModel in MVC3 action using jQuery $.Post()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I'm trying to post my date, picked with a jQuery DateTimePicker, from an input field to a DateTime property in my ViewModel. I keep getting 1/01/0001 0:00:00 parsed to it.
Let's have a look at my viewmodel:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Home team")]
    public virtual String Home { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Away team")]
    public virtual String Away { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Kickoff time")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public virtual DateTime GameTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Standard sharing on?")]
    public virtual Boolean IsStandardSharing { get; set; }

    //Hidden
    public virtual Guid PeriodId { get; set; }

}
```

Here's my razor for the inputfield:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.GameTime)
```

And finally my JavaScript

```
$('#GameTime').datetimepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    monthNames: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Zo', 'Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za'],
    timeText: "Tijdstip",
    hourText: "Uur",
    minuteText: "Minuut",
    currentText: "Nu",
    closeText: "Klaar",
    stepMinute: 5,
    hour: 12

});

$('#btnAddGame').click(function () {
    var testPeriodId = "245f83a2-52b5-4a21-815e-a0b40020d7ff";
    var valDdlHome = $('#Home').val();
    var valDdlAway = $('#Away').val();
    var valTxtGameTime = Date($('#GameTime').val());

    var valRdnIsStandardSharing = $('#IsStandardSharing').val();
    var postUrl = "/period/saveperiodgame/";

    $.post(
        postUrl,
        { Home: valDdlHome, Away: valDdlAway, GameTime: valTxtGameTime, IsStandardSharing: valRdnIsStandardSharing, PeriodId: testPeriodId },
        function (data) {
            if (data.Status == 200) {
                console.log("Game added. Id:" + data.Data);
                if ($('#emptyText').length > 0) {
                    $('#emptyText').hide();
                }
                MijnProno.fn.BuildPeriodGameTableRow(valTxtGameTime, valDdlHome, valDdlAway, data.Data);
            } else if (data.Status == 500) {
                console.log("Failed to add game");
            } else {
                console.log("Fault with Javascript");
            }
        }, "json"
    );
});
```

Been reading and trying answer on SO all the afternoon but didn't managed to get it to work (I always wait to long to ask questions like this because of possible duplicates).

After reading some highly upvoted posts I suppose I have to post my date like the /Date(1224043200000)/ format to let my ViewModel understand it.
Is this right? If so, how can I get my mm/dd/yyyy hh:ss format convert to json?

Comment: Not sure about MVC, but ASMX will _give_ you the /Date(UNIXTIMESTAMP)/ format, but will __accept__ ISO8601 in a JSON request and correctly parse it into a `DateTime` object. I would `new Date(Date.parse(valTxtGameTime))` in your AJAX request and see what happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for this problem. 
A [blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) drove me to the solution.
I think I must have tried every way to parse my date except this one

```
//JAVASCRIPT CODE
var valTxtGameTime = $('#GameTime').val();    
new Date(valTxtGameTime).toJSON()
```

Checking my HTTP Post, the date is now posted as...

```
2012-08-24T19:50:00.000Z
```

...and correctly received in my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, try this:

```
$.post(
    postUrl,
    { Home: valDdlHome, Away: valDdlAway, GameTime: new Date(Date.parse(valTxtGameTime)), IsStandardSharing: valRdnIsStandardSharing, PeriodId: testPeriodId },
    function (data) {
        if (data.Status == 200) {
            console.log("Game added. Id:" + data.Data);
            if ($('#emptyText').length > 0) {
                $('#emptyText').hide();
            }
            MijnProno.fn.BuildPeriodGameTableRow(valTxtGameTime, valDdlHome, valDdlAway, data.Data);
        } else if (data.Status == 500) {
            console.log("Failed to add game");
        } else {
            console.log("Fault with Javascript");
        }
    }, "json"
);
```

Comment: Same like above, new Date(Date.parse(valTxtGameTime)), gives me Aug 23 2012 12:00:00 GMT+0200. Will check your other comment now.

Comment: I think that must be an anomaly between (browser side) JSON-style encoding and POST-style encoding. If you'd like to see what I mean: run `JSON.stringify({myDate: new Date()})` in a Chrome console

Comment: I'd love to, but if I start up Chrome on a 64bit bootcamp windows, my mac freezes a few minutes later. Worst bug ever. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the date in different format via datepicker itself. e.g.

```
var valTxtGameTime =  $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#GameTime').val());
```

**[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate)** is the complete reference.

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: This will only work for the date. jQuery datetimepicker is an extension to the jQuery datepicker. 
Since the latest release they have added a .parseDateTime function to it aswell, trying to get that to work now.

Comment: Okay, got the parseDateTime function working. 
Unfortunately, it does the same as Date($'#GameTime').val()).
Post contains: Thu Aug 23 2012 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time), not a JSON like /Date(1224043200000)/

Comment: `/Date(1224043200000)/` is only JSON-like for Microsoft-based webservices (WCF, ASMX, apparently MVC). That said, I still would put money on the JSON-(de)serializer auto-converting if you can get the post request to send an ISO8601 formatted date (e.g. 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 (from http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime))